# Tablix column headers shown on succeeding pages

Tags: sql

Is there a way that I can show the column headers on succeeding pages on SSRS 2008?
I'm using ReportBuilder 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/d75b382c-f314-430c-9b04-fea007be9315/

you can also see step by step procedures here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

happy reporting! :))

Answer (score 1):

go to tablix properties then set RepeatColumnHeaders to True.